# Select data from 2 Field and use only 1 values

Tags: sql, oracle

Let says i've data like below.

```
Col1    Col2
 A       E
 C       C   
         C
 D       
 G       C
```

and output will be like below

```
Column
  A    
  C       
  C    
  D       
  G
```

So i want only take value that has a value, if that both columns has a value, take only from column1 only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select nvl(col1,col2) from table1
```

NVL will check whether col1 is null if not it will take col1 value. If null it will take second col2 value

Answer (score 2):

Also you could use `CASE` for common approach.

```
SELECT CASE
     WHEN col1 IS NULL THEN col2
     ELSE col1
   END
FROM table1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use **COALESCE**.

For example,

```
SQL> WITH sample_data AS(
  2  SELECT 'A' col1, 'E' col2 FROM dual UNION ALL
  3  SELECT 'C' col1, 'C' col2 FROM dual UNION ALL
  4  SELECT '' col1, 'C' col2 FROM dual UNION ALL
  5  SELECT 'D' col1, '' col2 FROM dual UNION ALL
  6  SELECT 'G' col1, 'C' col2 FROM dual
  7  )
  8  SELECT COALESCE(col1, col2) val FROM sample_data;

V
-
A
C
C
D
G

SQL>
```